# How to split by CHR(10) and move cells down?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bunch of cells that contain data like this.

1. Update Lending Information
2. Approve Lending Information
3. Update Fair Information
4. Approve Information

I want to split that into 4 separate cells and pull down the data in ColA and ColC.

So, if A1:C1 looks like this.

```
7   1. Update Lending Information   Conditional on question(s):
    2. Approve Lending Information
    3. Update Fair Information
    4. Approve Information
```

I want A4:C4 to look like this after the code runs.

```
7     1. Update Lending Information    Conditional on question(s):
7     2. Approve Lending Information   Conditional on question(s):
7     3. Update Fair Information       Conditional on question(s):
7     4. Approve Information           Conditional on question(s):
```

This is my non-working code.

```
Sub TestingScript()

Dim c As Integer
LRow = Sheets("Exception Report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For c = LRow To 1 Step -1
    Range("B" & c).Select
    splitVals = Split(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & c).Value, Chr(10))
    totalVals = UBound(splitVals) / 2
    Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1 + totalVals, ActiveCell.Column)).Value = splitVals

    'With Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    '    .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    '    .Value = .Value
    'End With
Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim iRow As Long, nRows As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    With Sheets("Exception Report")
        For iRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
            With .Cells(iRow, 1)
                arr = Split(.Offset(, 1).value, Chr(10))
                nRows = UBound(arr)
                .Offset(1).Resize(nRows).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
                .Resize(nRows + 1).value = .value
                .Offset(, 1).Resize(nRows + 1).value = .Application.Transpose(arr)
                .Offset(, 2).Resize(nRows + 1).value = .Offset(, 2).value
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```